# Graph Lifecycle Events With DelegateAuthenticationProvider

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

We are using the DelegateAuthenticationProvider approach with Graph in order to manage Graph subscriptions on behalf of our users. I am in the process of writing a service that processes any lifecycle notifications that we receive as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-outlook-authz.
I am just wondering with regards to the "subscriptionRemoved" life cycle event, if we are managing the subscriptions using essentially a generic account, does this mean that we won't get notified if the users account password changes or is revoked? In this case, will the notifications keep on flowing as the generic account won't be revoked or is it based on the account that we are creating the subscription for?
Sorry if thats confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i will do like the following: If my app is subscribing and when i see one of the event happens, (1) User's password has been reset (2) User's device is out of compliance (3) User's account has been revoked, then Microsoft Graph sends a special lifecycle notification, subscriptionRemoved.

As my app is subscribing to change notifications then i would listen to the subscriptionRemoved and missed signals. In addition, i will do this: (a) when i receive a subscriptionRemoved lifecycle notification, the app should recreate the subscription in order to maintain a continuous flow. (b) On receiving a missed lifecycle notification, the app should resynchronize resource data using Microsoft Graph.